# Getting error when connecting to ssh

Tags: ssh

Whenever I log into my Linux server using SSH, I get this error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I dont know which OS you use but it looks like an firewall Problem. Can you please give additional informations?

Answer (score 1):

I would also double check iptables by "sudo iptables -L" to make sure ssh (port 22) isn't blocked.

Comment: Highly unlikely as socket has been opened successfully but closed shortly for whatever reason.